# How to filter data by only one value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a working example of multiple filter (view at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/EKCTPEMICT/pen/YGwvam)) to sort amont of data by Material and Construction parameters.

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedMaterial" ng-options="emp.material as emp.material for emp in empList | unique:'material'">
</select>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Construction</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="emp in empList | filterMultiple:{material:selectedMaterial,construction:selectedConstruction}">
    <td>{{emp.material}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.construction}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But this is a question: what i need to do to filter that data by pushing on buttons? Coz my solution not working...

```
<button ng-click="filterMultiple= {material: 'Steel'}">Steel</button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want to filter only the items with material steel?

Comment: Yes.  And unfilter items by clicking on "All" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in empList | filter:{material:selectedMaterial,construction:selectedConstruction}">

<button ng-click="selectedMaterial = 'Steel'">Steel</button>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you!  Its simply works! Have you a solution to clear filters by 'Material'?

Comment: Add a button like clear 
<button ng-click="selectedMaterial = '' ">Clear Material</button>

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answers, For multiple select, the values are to be passed in array. On button click of 'ALL', array of string values are to be passed.

Included ng-click for buttons in your code.

```
<div class="panel-body text-center">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
        <button ng-click="selectedMaterial = 'Steel'">Steel</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
         <button ng-click="selectedMaterial = ['Polycarbonate']">Polycarbonate</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3">
          <button ng-click="selectedMaterial = ['Polypropylene']">Polypropylene</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <button ng-click="selectedMaterial = ['Steel', 'Polycarbonate', 'Polypropylene']">All</button>
         </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the snippet, does this work for you?

```js
angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("MainController", MainController);

function MainController() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.valuesFilter = {
    material: "",
    construction: ""
  };
  
  vm.values = [
    {
      material: "Steel",
      construction: "Standard"
    }, {
      material: "Steel",
      construction: "Perforated"
    }, {
      material: "Polypropylene",
      construction: "Standard"
    }, {
      material: "Polypropylene",
      construction: "Perforated"
    }
  ];
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as mainVm">
  <button ng-click="mainVm.valuesFilter.material = 'Steel'">Steel</button>
  <button ng-click="mainVm.valuesFilter.material = 'Polypropylene'">Polypropylene</button>
  
  <hr/>
  
  <button ng-click="mainVm.valuesFilter.construction = 'Standard'">Standard</button>
  <button ng-click="mainVm.valuesFilter.construction = 'Perforated'">Perforated</button>
  
  <hr/>
  
  <div ng-repeat="value in mainVm.values | filter:mainVm.valuesFilter">
    {{value.material}} - {{value.construction}}
  </div>  
</div>
```